# Help with using VNC on remote Fedora Linux machine at login screen

Tags: fedora, login, remote, vnc

I have a linux machine at work running Fedora 29 / gnome.  I always leave it logged on at work so that when I get home I can remote VNC to it and keep working.

In previous Fedora's (16 I think) I found info on the web on how to have x11vnc start on the login screen so that if there was a power fail / crash / etc I could restart the machine and see the login screen via VNC.  This was in the pre-systemd days.

I haven't found a way to do this with Fedora 29.  Although x11vnc is running once there is a login at work I can't find the magic potion that will allow me to login remotely via VNC.  Now that I'm working at home full time I have no way to start a session that will remain even after logging off.  I have to try to find someone physically at work and explain how to get to the machine and give them my password to get a VNC session running (Yes, VNC is password protected).

Does anyone out there know how to setup Fedora 29 / gnome to start with the login screen?  Lacking that, is there a way to cause this to happen via telnet/ssh?  Tunneling through ssh doesn't seem to be a viable option since I'm running Win10 on a company configured laptop.

Here's /usr/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=X11vnc
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/root/X11vnc_init
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=X11VNC
SyslogFacility=local5
SyslogLevel=debug
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

...and here's /root/X11vnc_init:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

if($ARGV[0] eq "stop"){system("killall -9 x11vnc"); exit 0;}
$DM="";
$LIGHT=`pgrep -x lightdm`; chomp $LIGHT;
if($LIGHT){
 $DM="lightdm"; 
 print "Found Lightdm Display manager\n";
 goto nextstep;
}
$KDM=`pgrep -x kdm`; chomp $KDM;
if($KDM){
 $DM="kdm";
 print "Found KDM Display manager\n";
 goto nextstep;
}
$GDM=`pgrep -x gdm`; chomp $GDM;
if($GDM){
 $DM="gdm";
 $dm=`ps ax |grep gdm |grep \\\\-auth |grep -v grep`;chomp $dm;
 ($junk1,$junk2)=split(/-auth /,$dm);
 ($junk3,$junk4)=split(/\/gdm\/Xauthority /,$junk2);
 $authfile="$junk3/gdm/Xauthority";
 print "Found GDM Display manager with authfile $authfile\n";
 goto nextstep;
}
$XDM=`pgrep -x xdm`; chomp $XDM;
if($XDM){
 $dm=`ps ax |grep xdm |grep authdir |grep -v grep`; chomp $dm;
 ($a,$filename)=split(/authdir\/authfiles\//,$dm);
 $authfile="/var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/$filename";
 $DM="xdm";
 print "Found XDM Display manager with authfile $authfile\n";
 goto nextstep;
}
$SDDM=`pgrep -x sddm`; chomp $SDDM;
if($SDDM){
 $dm=`ps ax |grep sddm |grep var/run |grep -v grep`; chomp $dm;
 ($junk1,$junk2)=split(/-background/,$dm);
 ($junk3,$junk4)=split(/var\/run\/sddm\//,$junk1);
 $filename="/var/run/sddm/$junk4";
 $authfile="$filename";
 $DM="sddm";
 print "Found SDDM Display manager with authfile $authfile\n";
 goto nextstep;
}
nextstep:
if($DM eq "gdm"){$AUTH="-auth $authfile";}
if($DM eq "lightdm"){ $AUTH="-auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 ";}
if($DM eq "kdm" ){ $AUTH="-auth guess ";}
if($DM eq "xdm" || $DM eq "sddm"){$AUTH="-auth $authfile ";}
if(!$DM){
 print "NO Compatible dm found\n";
 exit 0;
}
my $pid = fork();
$XCMD="/usr/bin/x11vnc \
-rfbauth /root/x11vncpasswd \
-nap -many -norepeat 5 -alwaysshared -dontdisconnect \
-shared -nolookup \
$AUTH \
-rfbport 5900 -no6 -xkb -display :0 &";
$XCMD=~s/\n/ /gm;
open tmpsh,">/tmp/tmpvnc.sh";
print tmpsh "#!/bin/bash
sleep 10;
$XCMD
";
close tmpsh;
system("chmod 755 /tmp/tmpvnc.sh");
system("/tmp/tmpvnc.sh &");
exit 0;
```

Thanks,

Marc

Comment: [These](https://gist.github.com/YourFriendCaspian/a1dc3b01c5423ee10893d74f9b172df9) directions should get you sorted. You can start it as a service with systemd.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try them for help in the issue but the Fedora installed x11vnc package does things a bit differently.  For example, the service starts at 'graphical-user' instead of 'multi-user'.  It also uses a perl script to check for the display manager (I'm setup with gdm) and get the display ID.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the text of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` and `/root/X11vnc_init`?

Comment: Thanks for adding your edit. Alas, that should be working. When it says it wants a graphical target, it means it's wanting X/Wayland to be up and running (according to my understanding). So, it should be running just fine with that configuration. I'm going to assume you checked and made sure the service is running and I know absolutely nothing about Windows 10.